# Recreating a sites HTML/Javascript navigation in Python

Tags: javascript, python, post, navigation, python-requests

Im using Python 2.7 and requests module.

Im trying to scrape data from a website that uses javascript to populate data. The website's navigation behavior is unpredictable with my script, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. The data I'm after is contained in pages for specific dates and I'm trying to get the last 6 months of data. So I scrape the first days data, increment my date, scrape again, etc.

The website is structured as follows:

```
/Monthly Calendar (calendarURL)
    Page 1 of date xx/xx/xxxx (when you click on a date from monthly)
        Page 2 of date xx/xx/xxxx (when you click 'next page' from page 1)
        Page 3 of date xx/xx/xxxx (when you click 'next page' from page 2)
        etc.. to last page of date xx/xx/xxxx
    Page 1 of date yy/yy/yyyy 
        Page 2 of date yy/yy/yyyy (when you click 'next page' from page 1)
        so on...
```

Page 1 through n of any given date all have the same url: `example.com/date=xx/xx/xxxx` (DateURL). The HTML for this page gets populated by javascript. Behind the scenes I see a request to a url which responds with the data I need. This RequestURL contains some parameters. One parameter I know indicates whether you receive closed/canceled items or pending items (p1 = C,A, or W - no idea what W is for). My dates are all in the past so everything I need is closed/canceled. The other parameters (p2 and p3, both binary) seem to indicate either 1st page of data or 'next page' of data.

for example:

```
p1 = 'C'
p2 = 0
p3 = 1
#this would return closed/canceled data for page 1 (FRequestURL)

p1 = 'C'
p2 = 1
p3 = 0
#this would return closed/canceled data for the next page from where you previously were(NRequestURL)
```

to be clear, these urls would look something like:

```
FRequestURL = 'https://www.example.com/index.cfm?p1=C&p2=0&p3=1'
NRequestURL = 'https://www.example.com/index.cfm?p1=C&p2=0&p3=1'
```

and FRequestURL returns first page while every other page is accessible by requesting NRequestURL.

There are other parameters in these URL's that seem to remain constant for all pages of any date. The only other parameter that changes seems to be a unix timestamp.

Note that these requestURL's have no date parameter. The date seems only to be in the referer header. The referer happens to be DateURL mentioned above. So I am requesting this data as follows:

```
s.post(requestURL, data = cookie, headers = {'referer': my_referer}
#this is shortened to s.post(requestURL) below
```

Before that my connection is opened as follows using requests and ssl:

```
class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('MainURL', MyAdapter())
my_referer = DateURL
s.headers.update({'referer': my_referer})
```

My problem:

About 50% of the time my first `s.post(FrequestURL)` works great. I then do each of the next pages for that date by calling `s.post(NrequestURL)`. Then I increment the date, update `my_referer` to reflect the next day, and start over calling `s.post(FrequestURL)`. This however ends up returning the same data for the first date, only formatted differently for some reason (2 items per page instead of 10). No idea why.

The revealing bit is that the other 50% of the time my first call to `s.post(FrequestURL)` returns data for whatever date I most recently visited in my browser. This led me to try calling `s.get(my_referer)` or `s.get(DateURL)` before every post but no dice it still goes with whatever I've been looking at in my browser.

I've also noticed often that I'll run the program starting for day 1 then it will exit with code 1. Ill then run it again and on the first request it will receive day 2 instead of day 1.

I tried to be as detailed as possible but I'm pretty new to programming so sorry if my language isn't descriptive enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried selenium to open the page first in browser but didnt work

Comment: Are you saying that your script gets different results depending on what you have visited with your browser without you sharing session cookies between the two?